# Javascript implement PRNG

Tags: javascript, prng

I'm trying to write a small multiplayer game, running as part of a website, utilizing websockets for communication.
Therefore client needs to be javascript, however server is golang.
The idea is to synchronize only by sending player inputs, meaning calculations must be deterministic.

This means I need an identical PRNG on both sides.
I found the java implementation:

```
seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
return (int)(seed >>> (48 - bits));
```

However I don't really know how to port it to javascript, where all numbers always are 64bit floats.
In theory the 53 bits for the base part of the number in a float64 are enough to store the 48bit long result.
The problem is, that the multiplication part "overflows" the 53 bits of accuracy, resulting in cutting the trailing bits (which are exactly the ones I need) instead of behaving like a modulo on an integer overflow.

How do I best work my way around this?

Comment: The easy way out is to use an existing PRNG for JavaScript.
This one is quite complete:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mersennetwister

Comment: I think in JavaScript you can force a number, x, to be interpreted as an integer by using bitwise OR at every occurrence: x|0

Comment: The Mersenne Twister seems to work. In case anyone is interested, my corresponding golang implementation is this: http://play.golang.org/p/laOFNFRhxi